# How many Voyager crewmen die?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

The ship has a crew complement of 141, as stated in the specs. They also pick up some Maquis on their way and a few alien species from the Delta Quadrant.

**How many of the crew (and passengers) of the Voyager died during their mission to get back to Federation space?**

Comment: Strongly linked to http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/50887/what-was-voyagers-final-crew-count

Comment: I dont care what the total is in the end, as that is so inconsistent and freaky that it can never be fully answered. the crew got bolstered by Markis, borg, ocampa, (whatever neelix is) etc. almost the entire senior staff was also killed off in the first episode. there are a lot of on-screen deaths. and in later seasons also a lot of additions to the crew. (birth beeing one of em)

Comment: Before you edited your question you specifically asked "how many make it back". That one was strongly linked to the link I gave.

Comment: In at least three timelines, the answer is "all of them".

Comment: @Valorum That would have saved me a lot of trouble. :-) Yes, in *Year of Hell* alone the body count is astonishing.

Comment: All of them, eventually. In every timeline.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If we consider Q's son as a "passenger" then that is not necessarily true.

Comment: @Hans: Hah, touché

Comment: There's also a thorough analysis on Ex Astris Scientia: https://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/inconsistencies/voyager-crew.htm

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## At least 43

There's an [easy-to-find list of casualties](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Starfleet_casualties_(24th_century)) on Memory Alpha, with a specific section for Voyager. There are 27 on-screen deaths and directly below that are five bullet points with off-screen deaths.

I've counted both the "astrogation department" and "entire medical staff" as two (or more) each, making the number of off-screen deaths 15 or more.

And then there is, of course, [little Naomi Wildman](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Civilian_casualties).

A total of at least 43.

Comment: Who could forget those who "died" in a metaphysical sense but were never actually pronounced deceased.  RIP Tuvix and alternate reality Harry Kim, you will be missed!

Comment: In the episode deadlock the entire crew dies, this is NOT a time travel episode so it was never 'undone', at the time of duplication the voyager crew count doubled and the self destruct killed all but 2 of them. So technically the whole crew died and stayed dead by the end of that episode drastically increasing the body count. (Tom Riker from TNG was classed as alive and a separate entity from the original when duplicated so the whole crew also share that status) +1 though